# Xcode Static Analyser reports one leak under ARC - CFImageRef - how to resolve

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, cgimageref

Out of some 2k lines of code, the Static Analyser has only one problem, thus:

```
spellDetailModalViewController  *detailVC = [[spellDetailModalViewController alloc]init];
UIImage *tempImage = self.spellImageView.image;
CGRect newSize = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 305.0);
CGImageRef temp = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([tempImage CGImage], newSize);
UIImage *passingImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:temp];
temp=nil;
```

It is complaining that CGImageRef 'temp' is 'potentially' being leaked, and has a retain count of +1. I set it to nil after the image has been passed to the modal ViewController. Obviously, under ARC, I can't call [temp release] under ARC. Not sure what to do.
Help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `CGImageRelease` `temp`

```
CGImageRef temp = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([tempImage CGImage], newSize);
UIImage *passingImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:temp];
CGImageRelease(temp);
```

From the `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect` Apple docs:

The resulting image retains a reference to the original image, which means you may release the original image after calling this function.

Comment: Many thanks @CocoaFu - that has solved it immediately. I couldn't find that in the docs, hence my question. I really appreciate your help - cheers.

Comment: @CocoaFu you're welcome =) i can't remember with certainty if the change i made actually makes any difference (beyond the ability to pass `NULL` without an error).

Answer (score 0):

`CGImage` is a `Core Graphics` object and ARC can not handle Core Libraries. So you should use `CGImageRelease` or better way to pass that warning, use `imageWithCIImage` method like that;

```
CIImage *fooImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:temp.CGImage];
UIImage *passingImage = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:fooImage];
```